# javascript function this and prototype

Tags: javascript, function, properties, this

The code is below:

```js
function A() {
    this.name = "kl";
    this.obj2 = { a: 1 };
}

A.prototype.city = "china";
A.prototype.obj = {age: 30};

var a = new A();
var b = new A();

a.name = "kobe";
a.obj.age = 20;
a.city = "American"
a.obj2.a = 30;

console.log(b.name);   // k1
console.log(b.city);   // why china ?
  
console.log(b.obj);     // when b.city = china, why b.obj = {age: 20}
console.log(b.obj2);   // {a: 1}
```

My opinion is that a and b has its own this, so how you edit this[property] you can't change b its own this.value;

property declare so share property ? is right ?
but when obj is change will effect b.obj, 
when city change will not effect b.city ?

Comment: It's rarely the case that you will want to use the prototype mechanism to share values among instances. It can give rise to hard-to-understand behaviors like the one you've found. It is safer to think of the prototype as a repository for **methods** shared across instances.

Answer (score 4):

Both objects have `city` and `obj` in their prototype chain. However, if you do `a.city = "American"` you are *creating a new property* `city` on `a` itself, shadowing the property `city` in the property chain.
Assigning to a property will (almost) always create that property on the object itself.

`a.obj.age = 20;` however *reads* (not assigns!) the object referenced by `a.obj` and updates its `age` property. `a` and `b` have the same prototype and thus `a.obj` and `b.obj` resolves to the same object. If the object is mutated in any way it will affect `a` and `b` in the same way.

Structure from the Chrome console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this line by line:

- First of all, `A.prototype` points to an object.
- When you run `var a = new A();`

  1. You create a new object which is set to 'this'
  2. This new object has properties `name` and `obj2` which have values `kl` and `{ a: 1 }`
  3. this object is linked to the object A.prototype points to, thus a prototype chain is set up.
  4. at the end of `function A`, the function actually runs `return this;`, which literally returns the object created to be assigned to `a`.
- `var b = new A();` does the same as above
- when you run `a.name = "kobe";`, you're modifying the value from `kl` to `kobe`
- when you run `a.city = "American";`, you're creating a new property `city` on `a` itself
- and when you run `a.obj2.a = 30;`, you're also only modifying a value.
- But when you run `a.obj.age = 20;`, something is different

  - `a` doesn't have the property `obj` on itself, so it goes up the prototype chain to the object `A.prototype` points to, and finds the property `obj`, so this line of code is actually modifying that `obj`, and changes the value of `obj.age` from 30 to 20.
- when you execute `b.name`, since `b` has property `name` with value `kl`, so it prints `kl`
- However, `b` doesn't have the property `city` on itself, so it goes up the prototype chain to the object `A.prototype` points to and see if it can find one, which it does, as previously you ran `A.prototype.city = "china";`, so it prints `china`.
- When `console.log(b.obj);` is run, `b` goes up to the prototype chain and find `obj` on the object `A.prototype` points to, so it prints `{age: 20}`